# E-Mail As Attachment link not visible in document libraries

Tags: document-library, email

For some reason, some of our document libraries do not show the "E-Mail as attachment" link in the edit menu.  I can't work out why this is and why some sites have it and some don't?  It does appear to be either working or not working, on a site-level (ie: all document libraries in a site either do or don't have the feature).

I'm sure it's going to be something simple that I'm just looking straight past!